# How to get $DESKTOP_SESSION from sudo script?

Tags: sudo, desktop-environments

The following sample script failed to get the desktop environment (DE) if executed with sudo. How to get the DE with a bash script executed with sudo?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $DESKTOP_SESSION 
echo $XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP 
echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP 
echo $SESSION
echo $MDMSESSION 
echo $GDMSESSION
```

Tested on Xubuntu and Mate, the returns are empty.

```
user:~$ sudo bash '/path/sample.sh' 






user:~$ bash '/path/sample.sh' 
mate
mate
MATE


mate
user:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `-E` option to `sudo`:

> **-E, --preserve-env**
>
> Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables.  The security policy may return an error if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

- see `man sudo` (or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/sudo.8.html)).

And run your script as

```
sudo -E '/path/sample.sh'
```

Answer (score 1):

Btw, in 2021, you want to use only the official `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`. Be careful that it is a *colon-separated **list*** (like `$PATH`), so don't assume it only contains a single value (even if it is in most DEs). If you prefer to handle a single value, use `$XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP`.

Official standards:

- [XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys), defined in the [Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) since its [version 1.2](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#idm45632483466576)
- [XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html#desktop=), best described in [`systemd`'s PAM](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html)

For more details, including a bash function to parse and test a desktop environment, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645761/4919